# I want to search prime numbers in 100 units

Tags: int

i make a code to search prime numbers

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 2;
    int a;
    int k = 0, j = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        for(a = 2; a < i/2+i%2+0.1; a++)
        {
            if(i%a == 0) j = j + 1;
        }
        if(j == 0)
        {
            k = k + 1;
        }
        i = i + 1;
        if(i%100 == 0)
        {
            printf("%d\n", k);
            if(k == 0) break;
            k = 0;
        }
        j = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

so i take number on hundred units(if 1~100 : 25, 101~200 : x...)
this program was activate so long time(3815 second) and return 0.
but i have curiosity on why this program stopped.
actually this program found a 0 or exceed limits of int...
so i ask my friend, but i don't take confident question.

please, anyone solve this question

Comment: You have never end the loop. Add some conditions to exit, or break it, your break statement breaks if statement, not a loop

Comment: There are a few issues with your code, since you have no exit condition,  `i` is never reset, and `a` is strictly less than `i/2+2`(i.e. should never loop around to -ve `INT_MAX` then approach 0), it looks like it should run forever, what error did it throw when it crashed?